# access the json encoded object returned by php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to post some data to php function by ajax, then get the encoded json object that the php function will return, then I want to get the information (keys and values) from this object, but I don't know how, here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "functions.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {id: id},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json){    
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){                 
            alert(json['fname']);
        }
    }
});
```

and here is the json object returned:

```
[{"id":"1","fname":"kjhkj","mname":"kjhjh","lname":"lname","prefix":"Mr.","suffix":"jhkjhk","email":"hf@dd.com","image":"11281454_423648214427141_318277024_o.jpg","info":"hjgvhd"}]
```

Comment: [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and/or [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Comment: `alert(json[i]['fname']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "functions.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {id: id},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json){    
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){                 
            alert(json[i].fname);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple to do this:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
    jQuery('.derp').append(item.mname + "<br />");
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fj0dytt/)

---

**Reference**

- [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)